# How do I define a App path in the new Django 1.7 App Registry

Tags: django, django-settings

In the new Django 1.7 App Cache/App Registry I can apparently define a path/location for my app.

I've looked in the documentation and it's not clear how/where to define the app's path.

Is it implemented by something like a tuple in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#configuring-applications :

#### Subclass AppConfig -

> from django.apps import AppConfig
>
> ```
> class SomeConfig(AppConfig):
>     name = 'python.import.path'
>     path = '/filesystem/absolute/path/'
> ```

#### Use it -

- `default_app_config = "python.import.path.apps.SomeConfig"` in `__init__.py` **or**
- `"python.import.path.apps.SomeConfig"` under `INSTALLED_APPS`